# Where is the command lines stored before it is executed?

Tags: bash

I have such a script in `~/draft`

```
$ cat test.sh
#! /usr/local/bin/bash

for i in ./*;do
    echo $i
done
```

The chunk of code are stored in `test.sh`,
when I run it

```
$ bash test.sh
./first.html
./second.html
./test.sh
./third.html
```

So I run the script name `test.sh` and get the output.

Alternatively, I could run the command directly as:

```
$ for i in ./*; do echo $i; done
./first.html
./second.html
./test.sh
./third.html
```

The second chunk get the identical results.

Since the preceding codes resides in file `test.sh`, what's the filename where the command `for i in ./*; do echo $i; done` live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands don't have to be stored in a file to be executed - the interpreter (in this case `bash`) can simply read the command line into memory like it would read a script file (with some minor caveats related to buffering) and then execute it in exactly the same way.

Comment: The command might possibly be stored in some buffer or pipe, which may possibly be found if one has the appropriate privileges and knows where to look for it (on Linux, using strace or mucking about in `/proc`).